# Swift - Call IBOutlets variables from another classes

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

I'm new to OOP and Swift and I have issues using calling `IBOutlet`s in other classes.

I've declared a var `IBOutlet` for a `UIImageView`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var deleteImageView: UIImageView!
    ...  
}
```

And I want to use it in a class `CircleView` that draws circles as subviews of a view. My goal is to know when the circle created intersects my `deleteImageView` it's deleted:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    @objc func didPan(panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        ...
        switch panGR.state {
        case .began, .changed:
        ...

        case .ended:
            if self.frame.intersects(deleteImageView.frame) {
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

In `case .ended` I want to access the `deleteImageView` but I don't know how to. I've also tried to create a function in the vc that accepts the `UIView` (circle) as a parameter and call it from my `CircleView` but I get an error. This is the next thing I've tried:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var deleteImageView: UIImageView!
    ...
    func deleteSubView(subView: UIView) {
        if subView.frame.intersects(deleteImageView.frame) {
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

and in the `CircleView` in the switch part:

```
case .ended:
    ViewController.deleteSubView(subView: self)
```

Error:

> Type 'ViewController' has no member 'deleteSubView'

How can I debug this?

Comment: Do you have a reference to CircleView in VIewController? If yes where is it?

Comment: You shouldn't try to access an IBOutlet from another class and the reason you get a compilation error is because your are calling `deleteSubView` as a class (static) method which it isn't.

Comment: Your circle view isn't the place to check for views intersecting. The circle views only job is to draw a circle. Your view controller is responsible for handling drags and checking for intersections and do whatever is required.

Answer (score 0):

Move your UIPanGestureRecognizer to your view controller.

The circle view should not be controlling anything, it should just be creating the view to display.

As a rule, you shouldn't be accessing another class' (including a parent view controller's) IBOutlets from a view.

The view controller should be doing the controlling. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers, i've change the code a bit, now in the CircleClass i just call a function that is in my ViewController.

it's like this:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
  var vc = ViewController()
  ....
  @objc func didPan(panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  ...
    switch panGR.state {
        case .began, .changed:

          //drags the circle

        case .ended:
            //when dragging ended check if the circle subViewIntersects with 
           //trashImageView 

            vc.deleteSubView(subView: self)
     ...
   }
}
```

and in the ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var trashImageView: UIImageView!

    ...

    func deleteSubView(subView: UIView){
        //let deleteFrame = CGRect(x: 688.0, y: 924.0, width: 80.0, height: 100.0)        

        print("my image view: \(trashImageView.frame)")

        if (subView.frame.intersects(trashImageView.frame)) {
            print("intersection")
            print("my imageView inters: \(trashImageView.frame)")
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
```

The thing is that when i initialize a CGRect for the trash ImageView (deleteFrame) it works just fine, the subView is eliminated, but when i try to use 
trashImageView.frame i get this error:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

When i use  *"trashImageView.frame"*  in the 'viewDidLoad ()' i CAN print the CGRect, 
but in my function deleteSubView (also in the ViewController) i get nil instead.

what can i do so i get the CGRect from my trashImageView in the deleteSubView function, if both are in the ViewController and that imageView doesn't move at any time.